# how to display my list from store at initialization with easy-peasy?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, store, easy-peasy

I want to get a list of churches from the store at initialization but i can't. The log get my initial array and the new one but doesn't display. Log below:
[log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdHLB.png)

here is my model:

```
const churchModel = {
  items: [],

  // ACTIONS

  setAllChurches: action((state, payload) => {
    state.items = payload;
  }),
  getInitialChurches: thunk(async (actions) => {
    const { data } = await axios.post(
      'http://localhost:3000/api/geo/closeto?latlong=2.3522219 48.856614&distance=10000'
    );
    let array = [];
    const resData = data.map(async (index) => {
      const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/api/institutions/all?idInstitution=${index.idInstitution}`);
      array.push(res.data[0]);
    });
    actions.setAllChurches(array);
  })
}
```

and my component:

```
const ChurchList = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const setInitialChurches = useStoreActions(action => action.churches.getInitialChurches);
  const churches = useStoreState(state => state.churches.items);
  const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = React.useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
   setInitialChurches()
  }, []);

  return (
   <div className={classes.root} style={{marginTop: '20px',}}>
    { churches.map( (church) => (
      <ChurchItem 
        key={ church.idInstitution } 
        church={ church }
        setActiveItem={setActiveItem}
        activeItem={activeItem}
      />)
    ), console.log(churches)}
   </div>
  )
};

export default ChurchList;
```

I tried a useEffect but nothing true. Could you help me please ?

Comment: share the `ChurchItem` code. also, have you tried `JSON.parse` before extracting your data? does the given l`log` image relate to console.log(curches) in `churches.map`? if yes, try to `return ChurchItem...`

Answer (score 0):

1. that is not a good location to put `console.log` in, either put it outside the component render, inside the map or on a useEffect.
2. You can achieve it by using useEffect and passing `churches` on the array.

```
  useEffect(() => {
   // this will log everytime churches changes / initialized churches
   console.log(churches);
  }, [churches]);
```

Comment: sorry but it doesn't work, i don't understand why

Comment: does the value of churches change?